# AS3 convert big number to base16 number

Tags: actionscript-3, hex, type-conversion

I'm trying to take a string, turn it into a number, turn that number into base16, and then turn it back into a string.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var d:String = convertBase("123487032174829820348320429437483266812812");

function convertBase(inputInBase10:String):String
{
    var i = Number(inputInBase10);
    var u = i.toString(16);
    trace("i = " + i);
    trace("u = " + u);
    return dest;
}
```

And here's what prints:

```
i = 1.23487032174829e+41
u = 16ae5514d07e12000000000000000000000
```

I'm trying to get `u` to fill out all the way. I know it's a bigger number than that.

Comment: `u` as decimal is `123487032174829820261288993992996781293568`.

Comment: Okay. I'm trying to get u in base16, though, except it's replacing vital information with 0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be warned, this is not the most efficient solution, but workable, given your numbers aren't going to be very long (very long would mean thousands of decimal places). The algorithm below implements long division using strings to record long numbers and then repeatedly divides the result of the previous division by 16, while recording the remainder into the result. This gives you the solution of the problem.

The code below is in JavaScript (sorry, I don't have AS compiler on this machine), but it must be trivial to make it look more AS by just adding proper type tags:

```
var source = "123487032174829820348320429437483266812812";

function longDivision(divident, quotient) {
    var i, digits = [], dividentPart = 0, resultDigits = [], nextDigit;
    for (i = 0; i < divident.length; i++) {
        digits[i] = parseInt(divident[i], 10);
    }
    i = 0;
    do {
        dividentPart = dividentPart * 10 + digits[i];
        if (dividentPart >= quotient) {
            nextDigit = (dividentPart / quotient) | 0;
            resultDigits.push(nextDigit);
            dividentPart = dividentPart - nextDigit * quotient;
        } else if (resultDigits.length) {
            resultDigits.push(0);
        }
        i++;
    } while (i < digits.length);
    return { a: resultDigits.join(""), b: dividentPart };
}

function decimalToHex(input) {
    var result = "", div;
    do {
        div = longDivision(input, 16);
        result = div.b.toString(16) + result;
        input = div.a;
    } while (input);
    if (!result) result = "0";
    return "0x" + result;
}

decimalToHex(source);
// '0x16ae5514d07e120126dfbcb3073fddb2b8c'
```

Answer (score 3):

Number as IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point does not have the precision to accurately represent your value; however, is approximately close.

There are [BigInteger](https://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/math/BigInteger.as) implementations such as [as3crypto](https://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/), as well as others enabling arbitrary lengths.

Examining as3crypto's BigInteger `toRadix()` and `fromRadix()` methods produce:

```
    decimal: 123487032174829820348320429437483266812812
hexadecimal: 16ae5514d07e120126dfbcb3073fddb2b8c
```

Example:

```
import com.hurlant.math.BigInteger;

var n:BigInteger = new BigInteger();

n.fromRadix("123487032174829820348320429437483266812812", 10);
trace(n.toRadix(16));
trace(n.toRadix(10));
```